# Returning a list of (x,y) coordinates in a matrix based on cells that holds a value

Tags: excel, matrix

I have a matrix of arcs between nodes where only some of the arcs exists (those with a value).
Ref:

[image: Snippet of matrix]

| d_{ij}^k | R01 | R02 | R03 | R04 | R05 | R06 | R07 | R08 | R09 | R10 | R11 | R12 | R13 | R14 | R15 | R16 | S01 | S02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R01 |  | 0.90 | 1.70 | 2.60 | 0.60 | 1.50 | 1.15 | 1.80 |  | 1.50 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R02 | 0.90 |  | 0.85 | 1.75 | 0.95 | 0.65 | 1.00 | 1.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R03 | 1.70 | 0.85 |  | 0.85 | 1.75 | 0.50 | 1.50 | 1.10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.10 |
| R04 | 2.60 | 1.75 | 0.85 |  | 2.60 | 1.25 | 2.25 | 1.70 |  |  |  |  |  | 0.90 | 3.10 |  |  |  |
| R05 | 0.60 | 0.95 | 1.75 | 2.60 |  | 1.40 | 0.75 | 1.40 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R06 | 1.50 | 0.65 | 0.50 | 1.25 | 1.40 |  | 1.00 | 0.70 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R07 | 1.15 | 1.00 | 1.50 | 2.25 | 0.75 | 1.00 |  | 0.80 |  |  | 1.65 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R08 | 1.80 | 1.00 | 1.10 | 1.70 | 1.40 | 0.70 | 0.80 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R09 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R10 | 1.50 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R11 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.65 |  |  |  |  | 0.60 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0.60 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| R13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.20 |  |  |  |  |
| R14 |  |  |  | 0.90 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.20 |  |  |  |  |  |
| R15 |  |  |  | 3.10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2.00 |  |  |  |
| R16 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2.00 |  |  |  |  |
| S01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

What I am trying to do is to get a list of the arcs that exists e.g. (R01,R02), (R01,R03) etc.

I have tried combining the IF statement with CONCATENATE, but I fail to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve your desired result could be the use of the `LET` function (available for e.g., Microsoft 365). Generally the function allows to assign names to computed results, and thus, also storing computed results, values etc.

```
=LET(name, name_value, calculation)
```

The following concrete implementation uses the following steps:

(I) Specify the ranges of your data (without row_headers and column_headers), row_headers, and column_headers respectively.

(II) You need to determine the coordinates of all non_empty_cells. Thus, you must first determine which cells are blank. For the blank cells you do not want to return anything and for all other cells you want to return the coordinates accordingly. This step returns a matrix with the coordinates in the respective non-empty cells (to see this, you can change the last specification of "result" in the formula to "non_empty_cells").

(III) Since you want to return it as a single list rather than a matrix, you gather your pairs and put them into the proper output format by putting the pairs in paranthesis and then joining them all together with `TEXTJOIN()` to form one list accordingly.

(IV) You return your results, i.e., the final list with all the coordinates of the non-empty cells.

```
=LET(
    data_range, $B$2:$S$19,
    row_headers, $A$2:$A$19,
    column_headers, $B$1:$S$1,
    non_empty_cells, IF(ISBLANK(data_range), "",
    INDEX(row_headers, MATCH(ROW(data_range), ROW(row_headers), 0)) & "," &
    INDEX(column_headers, MATCH(COLUMN(data_range), COLUMN(column_headers), 0))),
    pairs, IF(non_empty_cells="", "", "("&non_empty_cells&")"),
    result, TEXTJOIN("; ", TRUE, pairs),
    result
)
```

The result for the first three rows/columns will look as follows (the delimiters can be changed as needed, both for the delimiters between coordinates and between pairs):

```
(R01,R02); (R01,R03); (R02,R01); (R02,R03); (R03,R01); (R03,R02)
```